# Only one of the two AutoCompleteTextView are showing suggestions

Tags: autocompletetextview

I have two AutoCompleteTextView controls on the same page: ACTV1 and ACTV2 and only one (ACTV1 ) is showing suggestions from my database . For each databinding action I've made a java class separetely: ACTV1.java and ACTV2.java.
  But if I am adding an intent filter (MAIN, LAUNCHER) in my manifest file for ACTV2.java class and setting in run configuration ACTV2.java as Launch Action then I won't get suggestions anymore for ACTV1 control but this time I'll get suggestions for ACTV2 control.
The two java classes are identically just that differ the name of some constants/controls name.

```
      package com.fishing2;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;


public class CompleteBalti extends Activity {

    //private CustomAutoCompleteView CompleteBalti;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adaperbalti; 
    @Override  
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_partida);



    }

    final TextWatcher textChecker = new TextWatcher() {  
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}  

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }  

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)  
        {  

              adaperbalti.clear();
              callPHP1();  

        }       
    };  

    private void callPHP1(){  
    String result = "";       
    InputStream is=null; 
    AutoCompleteTextView CompleteBalti = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.nume_localitate);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st",CompleteBalti.getText().toString()));

    {   

        try{ 
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.3.159/wtf/balti.php");  
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));  
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  
                is = entity.getContent();  
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);  
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
                String line = null;  
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                      
                        sb.append(line + "\n");  
                }  
                is.close();  

                result=sb.toString(); 
                result = result.substring(1);
        }catch(Exception e){  
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());  
        }  



         try{
             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
             JSONObject json_data = null;

             for (int i=0;i<jArray.length(); i++)
             {   
                  json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 adaperbalti.add(json_data.getString("nume_balta"));
             }

            } catch(Exception e1){  
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e1.toString());   

            }     
    }  



                                                      }



                        }
```